# Java Weka: How to Contruct a Missing Value

Tags: java, weka

I am using the weka java api.  How do I set a value as missing as in

```
instance.setValue
```

I am reading the weka source and I see

```
Instance.MISSING_VALUE
```

but it is protected.  How do I generally represent a missing value to the weka java?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here on creating Arff files.

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file

So for example in Clojure

```
(def missing-value 
  (Instance/missingValue))
```

And Java

```
double NaN = Instance.missingValue();
```

Comment: You should post the actual answer instead of just the link, so that it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Added clojure example